# Draw lines to intersection of two functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to draw lines to the intersection of two functions in Mathematica that can be manipulated with a couple variables each in the following equation:

```
Manipulate[
    Show[
        Plot[
            Tooltip[QSupply + q^PriceElasticity, "Supply"], {q, 0, 150},
            AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
            PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red},
            AxesLabel -> {"quantity", "price"},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}},
            PlotLabel -> Macroeconomy, Ticks -> {{{45, "Qe"}}, {{54.3, "Pe"}}},
            BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 12}
          ],
        Plot[
            Tooltip[(DemandElasticity/q) + QDemand, "Aggregate Demand"], {q, 
             0, 180},
            AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
            PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}
             ],
        Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{45, 0}, {45, 54.3}}]}],
        Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 54.3}, {45, 54.3}}]}]
     ],
    {PriceElasticity, 0.6, 10},
    {QSupply, -17, 55, 2},
    {DemandElasticity, 500, 10000, 100},
    {QDemand, 0, 150, 10}
 ]
```

I tried using the FindRoot function, but the output doesn't give a raw value (eg. {q->40.0123}. Is there a way to extract the value from the FindRoot output? Or is there a better way to go about this?

I also looked into using Mesh but it looks like that would only help draw a dot at the point of intersection.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a better way to format this code to make it more readable? Or does Mathmatica code have to be all on one line...?

Comment: Sorry, I added some spacing to make it more readable. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/121